# How long can Contax T2 work with a brand new CR123 battery?

Tags: point-and-shoot, battery, contax

New to Contax T2, I'm going to Europe for about 20 days and I'm wondering if I should bring extra batteries (CR123) with me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if I should bring extra batteries (CR123) with me.

It's usually a good idea to bring extra batteries. However, if you forget or lose them, CR123 are common enough that you should be able to find replacements somewhere.

*(How was your trip? How many batteries did you end up using?)*